# search a Binary search tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am trying to find a name within a key. I think it is retrieving it fine. however, its coming up as not found. maybe my code is wrong somewhere?

```
if (database.retrieve(name, aData))  // both contain the match
```

in `main()`

```
static void retrieveItem(char *name, data& aData)
{
cout << ">>> retrieve " << name << endl << endl;
if (database.retrieve(name, aData))            // name and aData both contain the match
    cout << aData << endl;
else
    cout << "not found\n";
cout << endl;
     }

     static void removeItem(char *name)
    {
cout << ">>> remove " << name << endl << endl;
if (database.remove(name))
    cout << name << " removed\n";
else
    cout << name << " not found\n";
cout << endl;
    }

   int main()
   {
   #ifdef _WIN32
// request memory leak report in Output Window after main returns
_CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );
   #endif

data    aData;


     << "Database Of Great Computer Scientists\n\n";

database.insert(data("Ralston, Anthony"));
database.insert(data("Liang, Li"));
database.insert(data("Jones, Doug"));
database.insert(data("Goble, Colin"));
database.insert(data("Knuth, Donald"));
database.insert(data("Kay, Alan"));
database.insert(data("Von Neumann, John"));
database.insert(data("Trigoboff, Michael"));
database.insert(data("Turing, Alan"));
displayDatabase(true);
retrieveItem("Trigoboff, Michael", aData);
retrieveItem("Kaye, Danny", aData);

removeItem("Ralston, Anthony");
displayDatabase(true);
```

retrieve function...

```
bool BST::retrieve(const char *key, data &aData, int parent) const
 {

for(int index=0; index < maxsize+1; index++)
{

    if (!items[index].empty) 
    {


        if ( items[index].instanceData == key )
        {
            aData.setName(key);
            return true;                   // doesn't return right away
        }


    }

}


 }
```

and defined in data.cpp

```
bool operator== (const data& d1, const data& d2)
{

return strcmp(d1.getName(), d2.getName()) == 0;

}
```

so this bit of code inside main() is where it says not found when i think it should be working correctly. both name and aData contain the right name that was found..

```
static void retrieveItem(char *name, data& aData)
{
cout << ">>> retrieve " << name << endl << endl;
if (database.retrieve(name, aData))            // name and aData both contain the match
    cout << aData << endl;
else
    cout << "not found\n";
cout << endl;
     }
```

Comment: Something is going wrong with all your edits (in this and other questions). First you ask a detailed questions with code, then get replies and discuss them and then delete all the content except half a sentence. This makes the question meaningless unless readers rollback your edits. Please leave enough material so that new readers can understand what is going on!

Comment: homework tag?  You don't tend to see a "database of great computer scientists" outside that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the BST to navigate through the tree - not looping over each item in your array, like others have said. Try something like:

```
bool retrieve(key, aData)
  retrieve(key, aData, parent)
  if (key == aData)
    return true
  else
    return false

bool retrieve(key, aData, parent)
  if (key == items[parent].name)
    aData.setName(key)
  else if (key < items[parent].name)
    retrieve(key, aData, 2*parent+1)
  else
    retrieve(key, aData, 2*parent+2)
```

That should work well! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no C++ expert, but is your == operator actually being evaluated? It's meant to take two const data references, but you appear to be comparing whatever the type of `items[index].instanceData` is and a `char*`.

I suggest you put some logging into the operator and see if it's actually being called - I suspect it's not.

One option to take the == operator out of the equation temporarily would be to make the comparison explicit:

```
 if (strcmp(items[index].instanceData.getName(), key) == 0)
 {
     ...
 }
```

On another point, I can't see how this is actually doing a binary search at all. It looks to me like it's just a plain list - you're doing a linear search within `retrieve` instead of comparing the key and going left or right down the tree (or returning "found") depending on the result.

Comment: Of course it is being evaluated. this line 
if ( items[index].instanceData == key )
fires that function.

Comment: You say "of course" - have you checked with some logging? It would help if you'd show the declaration of the "data" type, by the way. Given that `key` is of type `char*`, how is that being coerced into a `const data&` to act as an operand to the == operator?

Comment: (I'd also suggest that given that you don't know why your code isn't working, pretty much *nothing* should be dismissed with an "of course" response. Clearly *something* isn't working as you expect it to...)

Comment: It is a binary search tree however i am not doing a binary search.

Comment: i set a break point inside the ==operator and after ( items[index].instanceData == key ) 

it goes there and im able to see if its making  match.

Comment: I did what you suggested with
if (strcmp(items[index].instanceData.getName(), key) == 0)
inside retrieve and im getting the same results..

Comment: @Corey: Right, okay - so that's not it. So if you add logging within the ==, does it show it ever comparing the values which should be equal? You haven't shown any of the code for insert, so it's hard to know whether the data is really there... but if you log what comparisons are being performed (and the result) that should help.

Comment: Jon, thanks for your help.. I set a break point at if (strcmp(items[index].instanceData.getName(), key) == 0)

instancedata contains the name im finding and so does key.
im not sure what you mean by logging?
then it setsName and returns true..

aData.setName(key);
return true;

Comment: By "logging" I mean "writing out debugging information" - as you're already doing elsewhere. So if it's calling setName and returning true, what *isn't* it doing?

Comment: Everything seems to be working just fine. i don't gt it.  inside main()
if (database.retrieve(name, aData))

if name and aData both contain the same name and it was returned true shouldnt it evaluate true?

Comment: Presumably "everything" does not seem to be working just fine, because otherwise you wouldn't have asked the question. So what *isn't* working fine? What are you actually seeing, and what would you expect to see? I'm afraid the last sentence in your previous comment didn't really make a lot of sense to me - partly because there are too many ambiguous "it" references. Please edit your original question to explain what you're observing.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for sure without seeing the code for BST, but this looks wrong:

```
for(int index=0; index < maxsize+1; index++)
```

With the traditional conventions, it should be:

```
for(int index=0; index < maxsize; index++)
```

Beside that, it also seems your function either returns true or some undefined boolean. You should probably have a `return false;` at the end of BST::retrieve.